# Can I take golf bag instead of other luggage?

Tags: luggage, qatar-airways, sport-equipment

I am travelling from Gothenburg to Bangkok with Qatar Airways on an economy class ticket. I am taking with me a golf bag (20 KG) and one suitcase (about 30 KG). Is this okay? How much baggage am I allowed to take?

Comment: You need to provide more information - What airlines are you travelling? In what class?

Comment: Qatar airline, economy class

Answer (score 1):

According to Qatar Airways, its [**Baggage allowance**](https://www.qatarairways.com/en-au/baggage/allowance.html) on the route is as follows:

> Flights to and from all other destinations
>
> - First Class   50kg (110lb) and a maximum dimension of 300 cm (118in)
> - Business Class 40kg (88lb) and a maximum dimension of 300 cm (118in)
> - Economy Class 30kg (66lb) and a maximum dimension of 300 cm (118in)
>
> **Baggage guidelines**
>
> 1. Maximum dimension = length + width + height;
> 2. A single piece of checked baggage should weigh no more than 32kg (70lb). Any bags weighing more than 32kg (70lb) must be broken down so that each piece weighs less than 32kg (70lb).
> 3. Excess baggage charges may apply if you exceed the weight and/or piece allowances; contact your local Qatar Airways office for more information;
>
> [**Excess Baggage**](https://www.qatarairways.com/en-au/baggage/excess.html)
>
> Excess baggage charges may apply if you exceed the weight and/or piece allowances
>
> **Excess baggage rate per additional kg (2.2lb)**
>
> From Europe to Far East
>
> - Purchased Online $40 USD
> - Purchased Offline $50 USD

You would want to read all the terms and conditions on excess baggage (via the link above), as one notes that:

> Excess baggage is subject to space limitations at check-in. If excess baggage cannot be accepted because of space limitations or airline initiated flight or schedule changes, it may be refunded or transferred to another flight with the same origin and destination, in accordance with the airline's policies